# How can i create layout like Facebook App's PostDetails view storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uistoryboard

My approach is like following:
I have a scrollview inside that i have Post's details(Title/Img/Description)in a view
i add a table view to show post list.
but that tableview size is fixed(& scrolling inside table view).
 I dont need to scroll inside table view. what i want is like FB stretch table view according to its content and no scrolling.
Now I want to add comments section like following:

[image]

Appreciate if any suggestions. I am doing it in swift and storyboards.

Comment: Are you adding tableView inside ScrollView?

Comment: Please try to explain what you have tried ? where you failed ? what were the issues ? so we can help give you a way to reach your goal.

Comment: I will use a tableView with table header (for post as in facebook), cells for thread (comments) and a bottom bar (might be table footer) for write new comment. For new comments i will create a view (as in the image you post) and will add to tableView's superView. This view has bottom spacing from `bottomLayoutMargin`. Than i will create a `IBOutlet` of spacing `constraint` and assign `constraint.constant` according to footer view's `height`.

Comment: Currently I have comments in a table view which is scrolling inside that but i want to stretch the table view height according to its number of items.(I don't need to scroll it.)